# Implementation of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, proof

The following text is snippet from algorithms book.

> We could draw the
>   binary trees using rectangular boxes that are customary for linked
>   lists, but trees are generally drawn as circles connected by lines
>   because they are actually graphs. We also do not explicitly draw NULL
>   links when referring to trees because every binary tree with N
>   nodes would require N+1 NULL links.

My question is what does author mean every binary tree with N nodes would require N+1 null links? how author came with N+1 number?

Comment: Try it out yourself.  Draw a tree with 1 node (2 nulls), 2 node (3 nulls), 3 nodes (4 nulls), etc.  Have you already done this?  If so and you are still stuck, we can show you the inductive rule.  It is not hard.

Comment: Another way to look at it:  every binary tree with N nodes has N-1 *non*-null links (again, draw some trees and see for yourself).  Since there are 2 links per node, you get (2N - (N-1)) = N+1 null links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could prove this by [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

#### Base case

1 node has 2 NULL links - satisfies the property.

#### Inductive step

Now assume that all trees with n-1 nodes have n NULL links. Then we wish to show, that all trees with n nodes have n+1 NULL links.

Take any tree with n nodes, and pick one of the [leaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_node). Remove this leaf. We now have a tree with n NULL links, per our assumption. If we add the leaf again, we lose one NULL link, but gain two. Thus, we have n - 1 + 2 = n+1 NULL links on the tree with n nodes.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a tree of 1 node, there are 2 null links (left and right on the root).  If you add a node to either left or right, you have filled 1 null and added 2 more.  This continues on ad infinitum, therefore for each node added you net 1 extra null leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: Each edge acts as a link. N-1 edges for N nodes.

Totally links: 2N.

Null links: 2N - (N-1) = N+1.